# Complex(?) htaccess rewriting / redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

It seems every few weeks I have to ask more .htaccess rewriting/redirecting questions. Every time I think I understand it, another wrench gets thrown into my project that shows that I don't.

**EDIT:** My original question wasn't very clear so the following is an attempt to be more concise.

As it stands, all of the .html files live in the root directory. eg: `http://example.com/about.html`

There aren't any sub-directories with the exception of normal ones like img, css, etc.

For tracking purposes, if someone types in `http://example.com/random/` where "random" can be any string of characters, I'd want them to see the `index.html` file, without modifying the url. The directory "random" doesn't actually exist on the server at all.

The same goes for other pages like `about.html`. If someone types in `http://example.com/random/about.html` I'd want them to see the `about.html` page.

At the same time, I'd like `http://example.com/random/about` or `http://example.com/about` (missing file extension) to *also* show the about page.

However, if someone typed in a page that doesn't exist, I'd like for it to use the `ErrorDocument`

Example: I don't have a file named "pickups.html" so the following would all be 404s:

```
http://example.com/pickups.html
http://example.com/pickups
http://example.com/random/pickups.html
http://example.com/random/pickups
```

It would be nice if the end redirect/rewrite did have the file extension stripped off (because it looks nicer).

My thoughts are that any request ending with a `/` would just serve up the index.html file that exists at the site root. So that leaves the files.

My thought process is:

- strip the file extension off of the request
- check if that file with an extension exists at site root
- if yes, display that page.
- if no, 404.

My initial code (had help on it) was this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.*)$ /$2 [R=301,L]
```

I understand that in that code I'm grabbing everything after the last slash and serving it from the document root. Unfortunately, it doesn't account for files that do not exist.

Comment: Testing can easily be done by a local Apache installation. Add PHP to look at the environment, but most of the time a plain Apache is sufficient.

Comment: After looking into this, I must admit, that I don't even understand what you want. I suggest breaking it into smaller pieces, and solving your problem step by step.

Comment: I have a local Apache installation - or XAMPP rather. What do you mean by plain Apache? I apologize if what I'm asking isn't clear. Anything specific that you're hung up on that I can shed more light on?

Comment: As Olaf says, there are two many dynamics to this question. It's difficult to answer in one. Please consider breaking it up as Olaf suggests, and tackling each piece one at a time. It's asking a lot for us to handle all this in one answer.

Comment: The fastest way to master this is to read the extensive documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/ and experiment in a test environment. The docs have it all, they are well written, everything is there. Read each document in that list, starting at the top. The Apache users email list is very good for support too if something is unclear. For testing I just use a subdomain of my site that is for testing this only, in its own `VirtualHost`. You just need an Apache server to play with Apache servers :) It's all simple really, just a few days of studying.

Comment: @SuperDuperApps Thanks for the information. Sorry that it's so much. It makes sense in my head (lol). I know it's a lot and I apologize. I was just trying to give as much detail as possible. I feel overwhelmed. :/

I'll see if I can think of a simpler way to word this post.

Comment: @SuperDuperApps I've updated the post. Does it make more sense?

Comment: With plain Apache, I meant just Apache, nothing else. Since you already have a XAMPP installation, that's definitely enough for testing.

Comment: The rewritten question is much more understandable now. What should happen with requests ending in a slash, but have a corresponding file, e.g. `example.com/random/about/` or `example.com/random/about.html/`? Are these requests handled as a 404, or should `example.com/about.html` be shown?

Comment: Ideally it would show about.html. I thought that files that ended with a slash would might conflict with the requests ending in a slash rule. Would it not?

Comment: Apache handles requests for existing files with a trailing slash as `404`. Unless you have special rules of course.

Comment: @anubhava I think that's the only way to do it. Otherwise the 404 page would never get viewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with existing files, they will be passed through unchanged. This also prevents rewrite loops.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Next are existing files, requested as part of an optional, virtual subdirectory

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(.+)$ /$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(.+)$ /$2.html [L]
```

This splits the request into an optional prefix `(.+/)?` and the file part. If this file part exists, maybe with an appended `.html`, you're done.

Next comes anything with a trailing slash, just rewrite to `index.html`

```
RewriteRule /$ /index.html [L]
```

Anything else will be requests for non-existing files, which yield a `404` status code.

---

In order to remove an optional `.html` extension and remove an optional trailing slash `/` for existing files, we must insert two rules at the beginning

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(.+?)\.html/?$ /$1$2 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(.+?)/$ /$1$2 [R,L]
```

These rules are similar to the other rules, except they do a redirect [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) instead of a rewrite, and have an additional condition to prevent a rewrite loop.

---

Putting everything together gives

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(.+?)\.html/?$ /$1$2 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(.+?)/$ /$1$2 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(.+)$ /$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(.+)$ /$2.html [L]

RewriteRule /$ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: This is great. Two quick questions. Is it possible to have an optional trailing slash for pages that _do_ exists as well? I tried adding `/?` to the second condition: `RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(.+)/?$ /$2 [L]` but that didn't seem to make a difference. So since `about.html` does exists, `http://example.com/about/` would show that page.

And this one is just a curiosity. If I type in `http://example.com/about.html` it will get renamed to `http://example.com/about` which is perfect. However, `http://example.com/random/about.html` does not get renamed. It displays properly though. What causes this?

Comment: The redirect (renaming) must be done by some other rule in your current htaccess file. I have not included such rules in my answer. Do you redirect all `.html` requests or just for existing files?

Comment: Weird.The only rules I have in my htaccess at this point are the ones you supplied. I did have other rules in place before, but I didn't think things like this would get cached or anything...

Comment: Strange, I just tested this again, and there is no redirect in my test environment. Then I inserted a rule to redirect `anthing/about.html` to `anything/about`, and now the .html extension is removed. Maybe there's another .htaccess somewhere? Or are there any redirects in some PHP script?

Comment: Ok it must have been cached. It's no longer removing the extension. So if I wanted an optional `/` for extensionless files that do exist, is that a separate rule?

Comment: Yes, currently `about/` or `about.html/` are rewritten to `index.html` like all other requests ending with a slash `/`.

Comment: Ahh - so that rule with the optional prefix is probably preventing that optional trailing slash. So I would need to write a rule above that to check if everything after the second to last slash would be a file. Is that correct? Also thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Please try the additional rules. They do work in my test environment, but as rules pile up, the interaction becomes difficult at best. So if they don't behave in your environment, remove these two first and then retry.

Comment: That works. Thank you so much. Looks like I have some learning to do for sure.